# MySQL datetime column shows incorrect time

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to insert a date\time value in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss in MySQL DB table using Sequlize as ORM in a nodejs (Expressjs middleware). For some odd reason the time element gets stored with an incorrect time. For example, I try to insert 05:50 PM but the DB column post insert shows 06:12 pm. Any idea how to fix this?

My model has below definition for the datetime column

time_stamp: {
type: DataTypes.DATE,
allowNull: false,
},

My DB table has below definition for the field

`time_stamp` DATETIME NOT NULL,

Comment: Are you certain that your both your client and database have the correct system time setup?

Comment: yes, they do. I am running MySQL instance in a VM which sits on my Mac and I did make sure that the time matches between system clocks.

Comment: [osboxes@mysql ~]$ date
Mon Jan 17 17:32:45 AEDT 2022 This is from my VM where I run MySQL DB. And this is in line with my system clock of Mac where I run my ExpressJS code which uses Sequlize to insert data in to MySQL DB

Comment: What is column datatype precisely? DATETIME or TIMESTAMP? What is precise SQL query text?

Comment: MySQL column definition is DATETIME and in Sequlize it's DataTypes.DATE. The issue is not with the query, it's with the insert. I use MySQLWorkbench to observe the data and it shows incorrect time

Comment: I hope it's not converting the value to UTC time on the fly. I saw some other posts on SO about how to disable UTC time using dialect option in Seqlize MySQL connection params though it was more for READ NOT WRITE operations

Comment: 1. Can you try to look at inserted data in some other tool, for instance, in DBeaver, to make sure you see the correct data?

Comment: 2. Can you get generated SQL INSERT query from Sequelize, check if it's correct and if it is then try  to execute it in DBEaver or in MySQLWorkbench ?

Comment: I already checked results from Mysql command line login. It shows the same date\time as MySQLworkbench

Comment: ok, even Sequlize log shows correct time, 2022-01-17 18:40:16 info: (services/dtMetricsService.js:12) **** New Metric Details : {"entityID":"HOST-F269FB79F89B4B60","metricID":"builtin:host.cpu.usage","timestamp":"2022-1-17 18:36:0","metricValue":57.30486551920573} . So, something else is going on here AFTER or WHEN it gets inserted. Is there any chance MySQL converting this to UTC at the time of the insert?

Comment: select now(); shows correct time though. 2022-01-17 18:50:11

Comment: `MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.)`

Comment: So if you really have DATETIME and not TIMESTAMP column type then converting to UTC is not the case

Comment: 100% DATE column...this is how it's in my DDL when I created the table.... time_stamp DATETIME NOT NULL,